# Populate a form on another website from your own site

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I am trying to build a webform that will copy all of the form fields to another, external website.  I am making a separate sign up form for USA Judo (https://webpoint.usjudo.org/wp/Memberships/Join.wp) but I need to send the formfield data from my version of the form to the original website.  I do not have control over the original website.

Any ideas?  I'm completely lost here.

Thanks.
-Scott

Comment: you'll need to write some code on **your** server - this wont be able to be done on the client side directly due to security - it may even be difficult to do server side, depending on how the other server handles registrations

Comment: The external website owners might frown upon third parties creating their own front-end for their site. Also, why the "json" tag on your question?

Answer (score 0):

The long and short answer is, unfortunately you can't.

Without having control over the original website, there is no way to pre-populate forms remotely.

The website you have stated also has a multi step signup form, which would make automatically filling it in not straight forward.

Cross Site Request Forgery is adopted in most modern browsers to stop sending forms to remote websites unless setup specifically todo so.